# Need to deduce $f(x)$ from $f_x=e^{t(x)}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function

I know that

$$f_x=e^{t(x)}$$

(where the notation $f_x=\frac{df}{dx}$)

(EDIT: $f=f(x)$ and $t$ parameterizes $x$, so $x=x(t) \Leftrightarrow t=t(x)$)

and that therefore

$$\frac{d^n f_x}{dx^n}=\frac{e^t}{\dot{x}^n}$$

(where $\dot{x}=\frac{dx}{dt}$)

I need to find out what the function $f(x)$ is from this information.  Help appreciated.

Comment: You don't know $t$ either?

Comment: $t$ parameterizes $x$. see edit above

Comment: "therefore" is wrong -- the second displayed equation doesn't follow from the first; this is only the case if $\dot x$ is constant.

Comment: $t=t(x)$ is not equivalent to $x=x(t)$. Please!

Comment: I didn't say they are equivalent.  The double arrow means "implies."  Doesn't $x=x(t)$ imply $t=t(x)$?

Comment: @joriki Could you spell that out a little more?  As I see it, the nth derivative of the first equation is given by the second equation.  I don't see how the question of whether or not $\dot{x}$ is constant is relevant.

Comment: @ben: Differentiating once yields

$$
\frac{\mathrm df_x}{\mathrm dx}=\frac{\mathrm e^t}{\dot x}\;.
$$

Then differentiating again yields

$$
\frac{\mathrm d^2f_x}{\mathrm dx^2}=\frac{\mathrm e^t}{\dot x^2}-\frac{\mathrm e^t\ddot x}{\dot x^3}\;,
$$

which is only equal to your expression if $\ddot x=0$.

Comment: Thanks for spelling that out.  I am confused about one thing: it seems to me the second term in your second equation should be $$-\frac{e^t}{\dot{x}^2}\frac{d \ddot{x}}{dx}$$.  You carried out the chain rule through differentiation w.r.t. $t$, but I don't see where you continued on to differentiation w.r.t. $x$?  I was not sure what to make of $\frac{d\ddot{x}}{dx}$ and so assumed it was 0.  If that is wrong please show me what it should be.  Thanks.

Comment: Funny, I found this comment because I noticed that you just accepted an old answer of mine :-) You didn't ping me, so I might never have noticed it otherwise. About your question: I don't know how you got $\def\ma{\mathrm}\mathrm d\ddot x/\mathrm dx$ -- that's two differentiations more than $\dot x$ has (one more dot and one more $\ma d/\ma dx$), and we're only differentiating $\dot x$ once, so that can't be right. What I did was$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\ma dx}\dot x=\frac{\ma dt}{\mathrm dx}\frac{\mathrm d}{\ma dt}\dot x=\left(\frac{\ma dx}{\mathrm dt}\right)^{-1}\ddot x=\frac{\ddot x}{\dot x}\;.$$

Comment: I could have just left it as $\mathrm d\dot x/\mathrm dx$, but I figured that wasn't in the spirit of the game, since you'd turned $\mathrm dt/\mathrm dx$ into $1/\dot x$ in the question.

Comment: @joriki: I thought maybe everyone gave up on this one because of my 53% answer rate.  Hence I went back and accepted a bunch of answers.  I didn't realize you have to ping.  As for the problem, ah yes I meant $d\dot{x}/dx$, not double dot.  Besides, after thinking about it for two minutes I understood your derivative was correct.  In the meantime I've figured out what $f$ is on my own, based on the assumption or postulate that $\frac{d\ln{x}}{d\ln{t}}=1$.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Well, you can integrate $\def\m{\mathrm d}\def\f#1#2{\frac{\m#1}{\m#2}}\m\ln x=\m\ln t$ to $\ln x=\ln t+C$, and thus $x=ct$, so $\dot x=c$ is constant, so that implies my condition.

Comment: @joriki: Ah yes indeed.  Ok, here is my last try for this post, this time putting no conditions on $\dot{x}$: $$\frac{df_x}{dx}=\frac{e^t}{\dot{x}} \Rightarrow \frac{df}{dx}dx=e^t dt$$  Integrate both sides to get: $$f=e^t+C$$  Does that look legitimate?

Comment: @joriki: Nevermind, I don't know what I was thinking.

Answer (score 1):

My idea, excecution heavily dependend on $t(x)$:

$\ \ \ \ \frac{\text df(x)}{\text dx}=\text{e}^{t(x)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}t(x)^n$

$\ \ \ \Longrightarrow\ \ \ f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}\int t(x)^n \text d x,$

$\ \ \ \ \int t(x)^n \text d x\ \ \ \ ?$

Ansatz $t(x)^ng(x)$:

$\ \ \ \ \frac{\text d}{\text dx}(t^n g)
=n t^{n-1}t'g+t^ng'
=t^n(ngt'/t+g')
=t^n(g\ \text{log}(t^n)'+g')
\overset{!}{=}t^n$

To solve

$\ \ \ \ g'=1-\text{log}(t^n)'\ g,$

which will probably look something like $h_1(x)+h_2(x) \text e^{\int\ h_3(x) g(x)\ \text d x}$.